# Adding images to Glance

Tags: openstack

I am installing OpenStack, i have installed all services including *Nova*,
*Keystone*, *Glance*.

I run this command to add cirros image:

```
sudo glance add -A 999888777666 name="cirros-0.3.0-i386" is_public=true
container_format=aki disk_format=aki < cirros-0.3.0-i386-vmlinuz
```

I don't get any error with this command, but it doesn't show any output
such as `Kernel_ID`. The command does not return any error neither it get executed successfully to add the vmlinuz.

Please help regarding this
issue.

Comment: Did you check glance / keystone logs?  Did you try tracing the command?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if the image has been added you can run the command "glance image-list"

In case the image is not there you can take a look to the logs to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

To be able boot vms with nova boot, you will need create proper image.
For that you need run the following commands:

```
#!bin/sh
kern_id=`glance add name="cirros-vmlinuz" is_public=true container_format=aki disk_format=aki < cirros/cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-vmlinuz|awk '{print $6}'`
ram_id=`glance add name="cirros-initrd" is_public=true container_format=ari disk_format=ari < cirros/cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-initrd|awk '{print $6}'`
glance add name="cirros" is_public=true container_format=ami disk_format=ami kernel_id=$kern_id ramdisk_id=$ram_id < cirros/cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-blank.img
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image directly via wget and  place the image in the download list.

Go to horizon , spawn a VM and use browse option and select the image. If the image is valid, it will work from there as well. 
This will give you a clear idea whether the download extracted the valid file!!!

Also restart the glance and reverify keystone grants to avoid any miss specially the parameter service password for glance service!!

Cheers!